# Efficiently converting a string to a byte array in C# (Not with Encoding)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, type-conversion, byte

How can I convert the string `"0100"` to a `byte` array `{0,1,0,0}` without using `Convert.ToByte()` on each element? The string may only contain characters 0 thru 9.

Comment: Following links should help 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp  2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545162/how-to-convert-string-to-byte-array?noredirect=1&lq=1  3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254003/string-values-to-byte-array-without-converting  4) http://rextester.com/discussion/HHSUSW47299/Converting-a-string-to-byte-array-without-using-an-encoding-byte-by-byte-

Comment: Are you assuming that the characters in your string will always be digits in the range 0-9, or always in an 8-bit character set?

Comment: @atur I said not with Encoding, example A becomes 65. Just 0 becomes 0 in byte.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, sorry I will edit this.

Comment: @JP_99 : Couple of links are without encoding. Moreover, see all answer not just the accepted ones

Comment: @JP_99 : Also it seems you just want to split the string by char (0-9) and aggregate the result in byte array. Eser's answer looks enough to perform that function.

Comment: @atur all answers in the duplicate link convert characters to their ASCII values, like '0'->48, '1'->49. Below code returns 1 for '1'. So it is not only *enough*, it is correct.

Comment: @Eser  Yes, I checked them all. Only your answer fulfills OP's doubt +1.   :)

Answer (score 5):

With linq

```
var bytes = "0100".Select(x => (byte)(x - '0')).ToArray();
```

Comment: What is the type of `bytes`?

Comment: I think that's going to give you an array of `int`. You'll need to cast the `x - '0'` to `byte` if you want an array of bytes.

Comment: @EricLippert You are right :)